# Index of ListViewItem Tapped in Tapped Event

Tags: c#, uwp

So, I am designing a Universal Windows app which uses a ListView with data bound to it which i create programatically. The XAML for my page:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEpisodeListSource" Margin="10,170,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EpisodeListSource}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Episode">
                <ListViewItem Background="CadetBlue" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" Tapped="ListViewItem_Tapped" IsRightTapEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Name="AlbumBlock" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="15" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                    Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ListViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

The data binds correctly and that all works fine. I am trying to then save the most recently clicked ListViewItem to LocalApplicationData. Currently, I am trying to do this by setting the Local App Data in the tapped event for the Items.

```
private void ListViewItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myData data = ((ListViewItem)sender).DataContext as myData;
        var clickedNumber = lvDataListSource.Items.IndexOf(((ListViewItem)sender));
    }
```

This is currently not working and the `clickedNumber` always returns -1 no matter which I click. Is there a way to get the index of the item which called the tapped event or is there a better way to do want I want to accomplish?

Thanks!

Comment: is `data` filled? and why don't you use `SelectionChanged` on `ListView` instead of `Tapped` on `ListViewItem`?

Comment: Yes, data is filled correctly and I am able to get the rest of the data saved in the `myData` type for each item. Would `SelectionChanged` work? Each item navigates to another page in the app when it is clicked. Would `Selection changed accomplish the same thing and what code would I use in there?

Comment: Problem is you are trying to access `ListViewItem` in corresponding to `Binding` on whole `ListView` through `ListViewItem_Tapped` which resources only to particular Item tapped. See my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting index or data corresponding to whole `ListView` (Parent Context) Instead of `ListViewItem` (Child Context) is always better.

Change your XAML to below.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEpisodeListSource" Margin="10,170,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EpisodeListSource}}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Episode">
                <TextBlock Name="AlbumBlock" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="15" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

and your Selection Changed event would be

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView view = (ListView)sender;
    //Get Index of Selected Item
    var index = view.SelectedIndex;
    //Get Selected Item
    var selectedItem = view.SelectedItem;
}
```

I would suggest always to refer parent resource and try to drill down to child unless you have a child click event which gives direct resource to get the parent.

Comment: I added the new event and added the XAML for the event in the main `ListView` but now when i click on items in the list, no event is called. The Selection changed event never calls. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Remove `ListViewItem` from your `DataTemplate`. I updated my answer.